# Ignore property when serializing under certain conditions

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Json.net has a very useful property that can be set on the `JsonPropertyAttribute` called `NullValueHandling`. If you decorate a property like this:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
string MyProp { get; set; }
```

Then if `MyProp` is null, it won't be included in the output at all.

I would like to do something similar, but with a different condition for exclusion. For example - say we have an enum

```
public enum MyEnum { None = 0, Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 4 };
```

And a property

```
MyEnum MyProp { get; set; }
```

Then I'd like to have `MyProp` completely excluded from the input if `MyProp == MyEnum.None`.

I know one solution would be to use `MyEnum?` instead of `MyEnum` and then I could use `NullValueHandling` again, but I can't use nullable here. I thought I might be able to use a `JsonConverter` so I tried to subclass `StringEnumConverter` (because I want them outputted as strings ideally):

```
    public class MyEnumConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter
    {            
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(MyEnum);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // don't write if value is none
            var v = (MyEnum)value;
            if (v == MyEnum.None)
            {
                // what to do here? The two options below both include the property as null
                //writer.WriteNull();
                //serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
                return;        // just returning without doing anything will break the serialization
            }
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }
```

Can I, or should I, try subclassing `JsonProperty`? And if so, what would I need to override to get the behavior I want?

I hoping to avoid having to attach a converter to the class that contains this property because then I have to manually serialize the whole thing, which is a pain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a method with the signature `public bool ShouldSerialize*PropertyName*()`.

```
public enum MyEnum { None = 0, Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 4 };

public class SomeClass
{
    public MyEnum MyProp { get; set; }
    public string Test = "aaaa";

    public bool ShouldSerializeMyProp()
    {
        return MyProp != MyEnum.None;
    }
}
```

---

```
var retVal1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SomeClass() { MyProp= MyEnum.None });
var retVal2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SomeClass() { MyProp = MyEnum.Value1 });
```

**OUTPUT:**

retVal1: `{"Test":"aaaa"}`

retVal2: `{"Test":"aaaa","MyProp":1}`