# partial or full object serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

Consider the following `Student` defintion:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public String FirstName {get; set;}
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Using C# serialization attributes, how can you apply two different serialization configurations?

When the object is passed to the `DataContractSerializer`, the user could specify "idOnly" (partial) or "full" serialization.

I have a two runtime use cases:

1. Only serialize the Guid
2. Full serialization of the Object.

Comment: Which serialiazer do you use

Comment: What kind of serializer are you using?  `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter` or what?

Comment: + DataContractJsonSerializer, JavascriptSerializer, SoapFormatter, Json.Net, Protobuf, ServiceStack etc

Comment: My apologies. Updated the OP. I am using DataContractSerializer

Comment: @bartonm I am 99% sure that what you want just doesn't exist. Typically what you'd do is have another property in your object that indicates what state its in, so you know whether any given serialized instance has valid name fields (for example) or not.

Comment: Look into using [`DataContract Surrogates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540.aspx) where the surrogate type chosen for serialization depends on your export state (all or GUID only).

Comment: @bartonm - updated my answer to use `DataContractSerializer`, now that I know it is what you are using.

Comment: @bartonm After reading dbc's answer, you may want to use another serializer like Json.Net. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293605/ignore-property-when-serializing-under-certain-conditions

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of serialization are you talking about.
But if you use the BinaryFormatter, the way to go is to make the Student class implement the ISerializable.

Then, you can do something like:

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
  info.AddValue("Id", Id);

  if (SomeCondition)
  {
    info.AddValue("FirstName", FirstName);
    info.AddValue("LastName", LastName);
  }
}
```

Where SomeCondition may use a static (or thread-static) variable or some information inside the StreamingContext.

Comment: I don't like this approach. I think there should be Attributes that I can use to decorate the Class definition.

Comment: Since the OP has now specified that he's using DataContractSerializer, this answer isn't as useful since that serializer ignores `ISerializable`.

Comment: bartonm, as you are using DataContractSerializer my answer is not valid at all. In any case, for the BinaryFormatter, that's how it must be done. I personally hate forcing types implementing a specific interface (or even using attributes) that are specific for a serialization framework, but unfortunately must frameworks ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, delete the answer for `XmlSerializer` because you're using `DataContractSerializer`.

One way you can accomplish this with `DataContractSerializer` is by use of surrogates.  A surrogate basically is a replacement class that you swap in for one of your "real" classes while serializing, deserializing, and creating schemas.  You can use this trick to replace your full `Student` class with a simple `StudentId` class depending (e.g.) upon the state of some [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) state variable indicating whether the full or partial student is to be serialized.  (I use `ThreadStatic` in case you might have multiple threads serializing data in parallel.)

Thus your `Student` class would become something like this:

```
[DataContract()]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
public class StudentId
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then your global flag:

```
public static class SerializationFlags
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static bool studentGuidOnly;

    public static bool StudentGuidOnly 
    {
        get { return studentGuidOnly; }
        set { studentGuidOnly = value; }
    }
}
```

Next you must create a [`IDataContractSurrogate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx) class telling the `DataContractSerializer` what replacements to make.  In this example you will conditionally replace `Student` when only the Id is desired.  Since you are only doing serialization, not deserialization or schema generation, most methods can remain unimplemented:

```
public class StudentSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    #region IDataContractSurrogate Members

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Student) && SerializationFlags.StudentGuidOnly)
        {
            return typeof(StudentId);
        }
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();
            if (type == typeof(Student) && SerializationFlags.StudentGuidOnly)
            {
                var surrogate = new StudentId
                {
                    Id = ((Student)obj).Id,
                };
                return surrogate;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And finally, here is an example of how it is used:

```
public static class DataContractSerializerHelper
{
    private static MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj, DataContractSerializer serializer) where T : class
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "    "; // The indentation used in the test string.
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string GetXml<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        return GetXml(obj, serializer);
    }
}

public static class SurrogateTest
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Student kid = new Student();
        kid.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        kid.FirstName = "foo";
        kid.LastName = "bar";

        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(
            typeof(Student),
            new Type [] { typeof(StudentId) },
            Int32.MaxValue,
            false, true, new StudentSurrogate());

        SerializationFlags.StudentGuidOnly = false;

        string xml1 = DataContractSerializerHelper.GetXml(kid, dcs);

        SerializationFlags.StudentGuidOnly = true;

        string xml2 = DataContractSerializerHelper.GetXml(kid, dcs);
     }
}
```

In this test case, xml1 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Student xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <FirstName z:Id="2">foo</FirstName>
    <Id>fa98b508-2fe9-4a09-b551-ba2ed1f70b70</Id>
    <LastName z:Id="3">bar</LastName>
</Student>
```

and xml2 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Student xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" z:Id="1" xmlns="" i:type="StudentId" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    <Id>fa98b508-2fe9-4a09-b551-ba2ed1f70b70</Id>
</Student>
```

which is what you seek.  Finally, note that, while my test case serializes `Student` as a top-level object, the replacement will occur if it is nested deep inside some class object graph.

For another example, see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/14/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates.aspx

Comment: And as soon as I finish writing the answer I see OP has updated the question to state that `DataContractSerializer` is used.