# Dynamically Emit Default Values from getting serialized or not

Tags: c#, json, xml, wcf, serialization

We have a WCF service hosted on IIS using the **DataContract** Serializer (Not XmlSerializer) our need is very similar to what @Surya KLSV posted "[Dynamically ignore data members from getting serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091785/dynamically-ignore-data-members-from-getting-serialized)".

Based on some business rules which we would not like to go into detail, our users can choose (by configuration) to receive, or not receive certain mambers in their answers. So we use **EmitDefaultValue = false**, when a user does not want to receive the **BirthDate** member, we assign the null value and it does not appear in the response (JSON and XML).

We are facing a problem with users who chooses to **receive** the member **BirthDate**. In some cases this value is not present in our database, it is **null** and when we serialize the response, this member is not appearing.

What we wanted for these cases is the member to be serialized with a null value. For users who want to receive the members:

**JSON**:

```
"Someone": {
    "BirthDate": null,
    "Name": "Josua",
    "Age": null
}
```

**XML**:

```
<Someone>
    <BirthDate xsi: nil = "true"/>
    <Name> Josua </Name>
    <Age xsi: nil = "true"/>
</Someone>
```

For users who do **not** want to receive the member

**JSON**:

```
"Someone": {
    "Name": "Josua",
}
```

**XML**:

```
<Someone>
    <Name> Josua </Name>
</Someone>
```

For now we are solving this in an ugly way: assigning the **MinDate** value on that, so this member is serialized in the response, the same for member Age, we are assigning 0 (Zero).

We can not change **EmitDefaultValue = true** because we will break the settings on clients that do not want to receive these members, unless, this is possible to done in runtime. Which we still can not find how to do.

We have already tried the solution from [Carlos's Figueira blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/25/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector/) but without success because the framework still respects the **EmitDefaultValue**

Here's an exemple to ServiceContract and DataContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISomeoneService
{
    [OperationContract (Name = "SearchSomeoneJson")]
    [WebInvoke (Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "SearchSomeone/json?Name={name}")
    Someone SearchSomeoneJson (string name);

    [OperationContract (Name = "SearchSomeoneXml")]
    [WebInvoke (Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "SearchSomeone/xml?Name={name}")
    Someone SearchSomeoneXml (string name);
}

[DataContract]
public class Someone : ISomeoneService
{
    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate {get; set; }

    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Name {get; set; }

    [DataMember (EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public int? Age = null;
}
```

Comment: DataTime object cannot be null.  The default value is 1/1/01 so you can either use the default value for null, or make a string and use empty string for null.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng we already thought about changing the type (string) but it generates modification on the users whos already using service. we are already using 1/1/01 as default, but hoping to find another solution.

Comment: You can modify the get and set properties to save value to a private property and still make it backwards compatible with existing users.

Comment: You might be able to conditionally replace your `Someone` with a surrogate, along the lines of [Conditional WCF DataContract Serialization (Using DataContractSurrogate)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417168/Conditional-WCF-DataContract-Serialization-Using).

Comment: How will the WCF client be able to distinguish between the situation where `BirthDate` is null, and `BirthDate` is not set at all?  The data contract serializers don't have functionality equivalent to the [`XXXSpecified`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c.aspx) pattern for tracking whether an element is present.

Comment: DataTime object can be null if you declare property as Nullable<DateTime>

Comment: @dbc After a couple of hours of DataContract Surrogate study I cannot realize how it can help me in this specific problem. I really will appreciate some ilustrated examples.

Comment: @iggyZoFrin, I'm using nullable datetime, isn't this you suggest? "public DateTime? BirthDate {get; set; }"

Comment: @LeoFraietta - OK, I found an example of conditional serialization using surrogates from one of my old answers: [partial or full object serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456638/3744182).

Comment: @LeoFraietta - OK, after further investigation, I can't find a way within WCF to suppress the ["type hint"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2009/04/22/understanding-known-types/) that the data contract serializers emit when encountering a conditional replacement type.

Comment: You may need to rethink your JSON/XML format, or switch to different serializers that support the [{propertyName}Specified pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842985).  That's [easy with `XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class) but not so easy with Json.NET [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3118504), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6792785).

Comment: With sure we used another concept to bypass this problem. Tks.